# Pytorch installation

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, local

I am trying to install Pytorch in python 3.12.0 and cuda 12.1 in windows 11 ? But I get the error

ERROR: could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch(from version: None)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch

I installed the nvidia cuda 12.1 as well

I tried to install Pytorch using the Pytorch website but it isnt working and is giving me the error
ERROR: could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch(from version: None)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch

Comment: You are using a too new version of Python, 3.12 probably has not received PyTorch wheels yet.

Answer (score 0):

Now, pytorch 2.2.0, 2.2.1 and 2.2.2 support windows with cuda 12.1.

By the way, I build a tool website for easy find and download right install wheels.

https://install.pytorch.site/?python=Python+3.12&device=CUDA+12.1